# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed when using datetime picker library

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development.
I want to create a customized date and time picker in my Application.

I downloaded this [library](https://github.com/seesaa/datetimepicker-android/tree/master/library/src/jp/seesaa/android/datetimepicker) from github to achieve this.
When I try to use it in my application, it crashes and I got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

Can anybody look at my code to see what I am missing?

```
import jp.seesaa.android.datetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;
import jp.seesaa.android.datetimepicker.time.RadialPickerLayout;
import jp.seesaa.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog;

/**
 * Created by MAC12 on 20-Apr-15.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    public HomeFragment(){

    }

    String tg="HomeFragment ";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        //  cls.findViewById(R.layout.fragment_home).setOnClickListener();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.date_picker_day);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ActivityCls cls=new ActivityCls();
               cls.Start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        try {
            Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("fragment_home");
            childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
            childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public class ActivityCls extends FragmentActivity
    {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          //  findViewById(R.layout.date_picker_day).setOnClickListener();
            DatePickerDialog.newInstance(HomeFragment.this, 2006, 1, 2)
                    .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            DatePickerDialog.newInstance(HomeFragment.this, 2006, 1, 2)
                    .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        //  Log.w(TAG, "App stopped");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //  Log.w(TAG, "App destoryed");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error. Including all connected log entries.

Comment: post exceptions first

Comment: The problem i supose is the format of tha date, try with 
            DatePickerDialog.newInstance(HomeFragment.this, 1, 2, 2006)
                    .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datepicker");

Comment: On executing  `DatePickerDialog.newInstance(HomeFragment.this, 2006, 1, 2)
                    .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datepicker");  `  statement it throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed`

Comment: What is the meaning of statement  "ActivityCls cls=new ActivityCls(); cls.Start();"

Comment: You're starting a new activity called ActivityCls. Check that this activity is in your manifest

Comment: Try putting "DatePickerDialog.newInstance(HomeFragment.this, 2006, 1, 2).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datepicker");" inside onclick method. remove "ActivityCls cls=new ActivityCls(); cls.Start();".

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager()  class dosen't support Fragment;thats why i tried to nesting a class

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html here you can see the format of the date is moth day and year, you are pasing year before then you have that exception.